# Не работает JQuery!

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, эффекты

Не работает JQuery-код, связанный с эффектами, в остальном всё работает в штатном режиме! Не могли бы вы подсказать в чём проблема?

```
`<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>effect demo</title>
 <style>
 div {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: #ccc;
 border: 1px solid #000;
 }
 </style>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <p>Click anywhere to apply the effect.</p>
 <div></div>

 <script>
 $( document ).click(function() {
 $( "div" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
 });
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте jQuery UI

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

чтобы функция `$().effect` была определена.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>effect demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Click anywhere to apply the effect.</p>
<div></div>
 
<script>
$( document ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```